# SwipeRefreshLayout can be used in a fragment inside action bar tab with swipe views for switching between tabs?

Tags: android-fragments

I implemented the new SwipeRefreshLayout component in my application and it works well with ListView.

And I also implemented swipe views using action bar tabs, but I can´t get the listfragment of the tab to work with SwipeRefreshLayout.

I have a FragmentActivity that implements ActionBar.TabListener for switching between two fragments and a ViewPager. Every fragment uses SwipeRefreshLayout to swipe-to-refresh the list but when I swipe to refresh the method setOnRefreshListener is null pointer.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues until I put the setOnRefreshListener in the correct spot.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener( new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
   @Override
   public void onRefresh() { 
       // onRefresh action here
   });
}
```